# Get Bundle name from its executable

Tags: cocoa, macos

Given the path for a bundle, how can I get the name of its executable?

Example:

> blahblah.app

should give me

> blahblah.app/Contents/MacOS/blahblah

Vice versa will also be okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *exe = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:thePath] executablePath];
```

You can also use the URL variants if you're on Snow Leopard and want URLs instead.